# Unwind Segue for UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I have a simple UINavigationController which pushes a UIViewController onto the stack via a custom segue.  I then implemented an IBAction on the first UIViewController to perform an unwind action and I implement segueForUnwindingToViewController.  Unfortunately, the segueForUnwindingToViewController is not being called (I did confirm that canPerformUnwindSegue is being called on the first VC).

I have not seen any simple examples of this behavior.  Can anyone please help?  Thanks.

Here's the code from the root view controller of the NavigationController.

```
- (IBAction) unwindFromSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
// unwinds back to here
//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"UnwindToObjectManageSegue" sender:self];

}

- (BOOL)canPerformUnwindSegueAction:(SEL)action fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController
                     withSender:(id)sender {
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
return YES;
}

- (UIStoryboardSegue *)segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController
                                  fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController
                                          identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
ObjectManageObjectDetailSegue *segue = [[ObjectManageObjectDetailSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier source:fromViewController destination:toViewController];
[segue setUnwinding:YES];
return segue;
}
```

Comment: I assume that you followed the steps from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12843906/335858) but things did not work for you, correct?

Comment: That's correct.  I followed that to a T.  Unfortunately, my unwind segue is not being called.  The identifier is being sent correctly, but it the segue itself is never invoked.

Comment: It would be great if someone could maybe post a sample project which exemplifies what was posted in that thread.  I think it's a great example, but it's rather spread out.

Comment: Where are you trying to unwind to? You say you're unwinding from the first view controller. Do you mean the root view controller of the navigation controller?

Comment: Please post your code for the unwind method.

Comment: I am trying to unwind to the root view controller of the Navigation Controller, yes.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem and I finally found a solution:
https://github.com/simonmaddox/CustomUnwindSegue

He also had a problem with it not being called.  Turns out that any view controller that is in a UINavigationController will not call the presenting view controller but the UINavigationController instead.  This means you must subclass that UINavigationController and add that method there instead.

Comment: OMG, I'd been struggling with this for about a day.  Thank you!  This really seems like a bit of an oversight in the way storyboards and custom segues work.  But at least I have something that works now!

Comment: Thanks Greeso. Probably person forgot. Also, glad to help Danny Sung

Comment: Thanks ! you sure saved me some time.