# Unwind segue to child view controllers not behaving as expected

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue, ios8.1, uicontainerview, unwind-segue

Unwind segues seem not to behave as expected in iOS 8.1 when combined with a modal view and container view.
Here's the view controller hierarchy for the test project which can be [found on github](https://github.com/memmons/UnwindSegueBug):

[image: Unwind segue bug hierarchy image]

Tapping on the "tap me" button pushes the modal view which is embedded in a navigation controller and which has a tableView as a child view controller. Tapping on a row in the tableView pushes another tableView. Finally, tapping on a row in this final tableView *should* call the unwind segue named `bUnwindSegue` found on the previous view controller.

Problems:

1. bUnwindSegue is never called.
2. According to technical note [TN2298](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591-CH1-CCVC) a container view controller is responsible for selecting the child view controller to handle a segue. In this case `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:fromViewController:withSender:` should be called on the container view controller. It isn't.

In the example project, you can see that `BTableViewController` contains the unwind segue:

```
- (IBAction)bUnwindSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
{
    NSLog(@"Unwinding...this unwind segue will never get called.");
}
```

In the storyboard, the cell selection action for `CTableViewController` is indeed the `bUnwindSegue`. Also note that if you change the cell select action of `CTableViewController` to the unwind segue in the container view controller -- `containerVCUnwindSegue` -- that the segue is called correctly.

Are unwind segues not behaving as expected?

Comment: Your unwind segue method should be in the view controller you're unwinding *to*.

Comment: @LyndseyScott BTableViewController is the VC that is being unwound to.

Comment: @LyndseyScott The unwind segue is currently set via storyboard. Changes would need to happen there as well. Alternately, you could remove the storyboard unwind and set it programmatically. I would expect both cases to behave the same.

Comment: Just realized I misread that second sentence I referenced... And I was generally confusing B C and TableViewControllers... I'm caught up now though and thinking it over..

Comment: The reason it's not transitioning back unless you put the segue in the container view controller is because unlike CTableViewController, BTableViewController hasn't been added to the stack as a standalone view controller, but as a container of your container view controller.

Comment: @LyndseyScott That scenario is covered under TN2298.

Comment: Checked out your code and I see a few issues... Will write them up in a bit...

Answer (score 0):

(1) You're misunderstanding the technical note TN2298 you cited and (2) you're not overriding `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:` appropriately.

As the TN2298 doc section you linked to about Container View Controller states underneath its  "Selecting a Child View Controller to Handle An Unwind Action" subheading:

> Your container view controller should override the method shown in
>   [viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:] to search its child
>   view controllers for a view controller that wants to handle the unwind
>   action. If none of a container's child view controllers want to handle
>   the unwind action, it should invoke the super's implementation and return 
>   the result.

First off, to override the method, you have to subclass the *`UINavigationController`* in your storyboard and add the `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:` method there. After doing that, you'll see the method is now being called as expected.

But your second error is that your current attempt to override the `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:` method simply contains `return self;`. You should instead be returning the view controller that you'd like to handle the unwind action.

So say, for example, you have a public variable in `VCWithContainedVCsViewController` to hold the current instance of `BTableViewController` and you access you're able to access that current container view controller, ex:

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:(SEL)action fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController withSender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Technical note TN2298 indicates child VCs defer to their parent to determine where an unwind segue will be handled.");

    if ([NSStringFromSelector(action) isEqualToString:@"bUnwindSegue:"]) {

        NSLog(@"%@", self.viewControllers);
        VCWithContainedVCsViewController *containerVC = (VCWithContainedVCsViewController*)self.viewControllers[0];
        return containerVC.container;
    }

    return [super viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:action fromViewController:fromViewController withSender:sender];
}
```

What you'll see in that case is that `bUnwindSegue:` is in fact being called (your message should print), but the segue still won't happen.

Why is this?

Because as I mentioned in the comments, `BTableViewController` is *not* on the current navigation stack. Some child view controllers of `BTableViewController`, like `CTableViewController`, will be on the navigation stack because, for example, `CTableViewController` is not a container view. But `BTableViewController` itself is not capable of performing the segue on its own because it is not on the current navigation stack. So although you can in fact select some child view controllers to handle unwind actions as the documentation states, `BTableViewController` isn't going to be one of them.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what is happening - `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction` on `VCWithContainedVCsViewController` is never being called. I'm returning self as a stub and placing a breakpoint there for testing purposes.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons I'm not misunderstanding. Like I said, it's not being called because it shouldn't be in your View Controller's class, but in your Navigation View Controller's subclass: "First off, to override the method, you have to subclass the UINavigationController in your storyboard and add the viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction: method there. After doing that, you'll see the method is now being called as expected."

Comment: Ah. I see this SO answer also recommends to subclass the nav controller (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092189/unwind-segue-for-uinavigationcontroller). Fair enough, but this is directly in opposition to what the technical note indicates, `If you are using the container view controllers provided by the SDK, such as UINavigationController, these are handled automatically.`

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons No, the technical note's correct. Your navigation controller is attempting to unwind automatically as it's supposed to -- it's just that (like I said in my comment and at the end of my answer) `BTableViewController` isn't actually on the navigation stack so it's not able to perform the unwind. By overriding the UINavigation controller's automatic actions using `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:` and *forcing* the segue in `BTableViewController` to perform even though the message prints, you'll still see that nothing happens.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons Also note that since `BTableViewController` isn't able to perform the unwind, the `UINavigationController` (if `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:` is not overridden) will keep looking down the nav stack so if you put `bUnwindSegue:` in the container VC it should be executed. (No need to create a different segue as you've done for testing in your current code.)